# Can't figure out how to join tables due to comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of the following structure.

```
select loginid,alloted_area from tbllogin
```

Which returns this result.

```
loginid       alloted_area
------------- ---------------------------
01900017      22,153,169,174,179,301
01900117      254,91,92,285,286,287
01900217      2,690,326,327,336
17900501      null
17900601      28,513,409,410
17901101      254,91,92,285
17901701      59,1302,1303
17902101      2,690,326,327
17902301      20,159,371,161
17902401      null
```

I have another table `tblarea` whose ids are stored in comma separated values in the above tables when an area is assigned to a user. I want to join these two tables and leave entries like the last one that has not yet been assigned an area. Now I have been told several times on  that storing data in comma separated values is a bad practice(I suppose it's because of the problem that I am facing) I know that but this structure has been created by another developer at my company not me so please help instead of downvoting. This is what I have tried:

```
declare @csv varchar(max)='';
SELECT @CSV = COALESCE(@CSV + ', ', '') + case when alloted_area is null or alloted_area='' then '0' else alloted_area end from tbllogin;
select * from tblarea where id in (select 0 union select sID from splitstring(@CSV,','));
```

This does get the area but there is no way it can give me the login of users that the areas have been assigned to. Sample input and output.

tbllogin

```
 loginid       alloted_area
 ------------- ---------------------------
 a1            1,3,5
 a2            2,4
 a3            1,4
 a4            null
```

tblarea

```
 id            area_name
 ------------- ---------------------------
 1             v
 2             w
 3             x
 4             y
 5             z
```

After joining I need this result

```
 login_id            area_name
 ------------- ---------------------------
 a1             v
 a1             x
 a1             z
 a2             w
 a2             y
 a3             v
 a3             y
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and clearly show us the sample input and the expected output?  I have some workarounds in mind, but your data is not clear to me.

Comment: This is going to be a real pain when data grows up. Though you are not responsible for table design. You can explain the problems in storing data in this way and get it changed to proper normalized table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Using Split and CROSS APPLY we can achieve the desired Output

```
DECLARE @tbllogin TABLE (LoginID CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, alloted_area VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblLogin (LoginID, alloted_area)
VALUES ('a1', '1,3,5'), ('a2', '2,4'),('a3', '1,4'), ('a4', NULL);

DECLARE @tblArea TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Area_Name CHAR(1));
INSERT @tblArea (ID, Area_Name) 
VALUES (1, 'v'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'x'), (4, 'y'), (5, 'z');


SELECT Dt.LoginID,A.Area_Name FROm
(
SELECT LoginID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS alloted_area
            FROM (
                SELECT LoginID,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(alloted_area, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS alloted_area
                FROM @tbllogin
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY alloted_area.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)

)DT
Inner join 
 @tblArea A
 on A.ID=DT.alloted_area
```

OutPut

```
LoginID     Area_Name
--------------------
a1          v
a1          x
a1          z
a2          w
a2          y
a3          v
a3          y
```

Comment: that's just brilliant. Could you please explain how this query works.

Answer (score 2):

You can join using `LIKE`, e.g. `CONCAT(',', alloted_area, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', ID, ',%')`

So for a full example

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @tbllogin TABLE (LoginID CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, alloted_area VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblLogin (LoginID, alloted_area)
VALUES ('a1', '1,3,5'), ('a2', '2,4'),('a3', '1,4'), ('a4', NULL);
DECLARE @tblArea TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Area_Name CHAR(1));
INSERT @tblArea (ID, Area_Name) 
VALUES (1, 'v'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'x'), (4, 'y'), (5, 'z');

-- QUERY
SELECT  l.LoginID,
        a.Area_Name
FROM    @tblLogin AS l
        INNER JOIN @tblArea AS a
            ON CONCAT(',', l.alloted_area, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', a.ID, ',%')
ORDER BY l.LoginID;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LoginID     Area_Name
--------------------
a1          v
a1          x
a1          z
a2          w
a2          y
a3          v
a3          y
```

You could arguably split `allocated_area` into separate rows, but the article [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand shows that in these circumstances `LIKE` will outperform the any of the split functions.

Although you have said that you know it is a bad design, I can't in good conscience not mention it in my answer, so whichever method you choose is not a substitute for fixing how this is stored. If not by you, by whoever designed it.

The correct method would be a junction table, `tblLoginArea`:

```
LoginID     AreaID
------------------
a1          1
a1          3
a1          5
a2          2
a2          4
....etc
```

Then if the developers still need the csv format, then they can create a view, and update their references to that:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.LoginAreaCSV
AS
SELECT  l.LoginID,
        Allocated_Area = STUFF(la.AllocatedAreas.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    tblLogin AS l
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  CONCAT(',', la.AreaID)
            FROM    tblLoginArea AS la
            WHERE   la.LoginID = l.LoginID
            ORDER BY la.AreaID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS la (AllocatedAreas);
```

And your query can be done using equality predicates that can be optimised with indexed:

```
SELECT  l.LoginID, a.Area_Name
FROM    tblLogin AS l
        INNER JOIN tblLoginArea AS la
            ON la.LoginID = l.LoginID
        INNER JOIN tblArea AS a
            ON a.ID = la.AreaID;
```

**[Example on DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7aa2d8304466b77bfd95d5177260353e)**

Answer (score 2):

Consider this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
      ) AS y
    );
```

Then you can do a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.loginid,tblarea.area_name 
FROM 
    tbllogin AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT value FROM SplitString(t.alloted_area,',')) as split
JOIN tblarea ON tblarea.id=split.Value
```